why my component does not render when click button again
when I click on button for the first time notification component was render but when I click on button again this component not render , why ?
what should i do for rerender notification component?
//home.cs

//some code with html

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm bg-juice text-light rounded-circle float-start"     @onclick="CheckProductVersion">
<Notification ShowAlert="@ShowAlert" AlertClass="@AlertClass" AlertMessage="@AlertMessage" />
//some code with html
@code
{
 private bool ShowAlert { get; set; }
 private string AlertClass { get; set; } = "alert-info";
 private string AlertMessage { get; set; }
 private async Task CheckProductVersion()
 {
 try
  {
   await UpdateWorker.CheckUpdate();
   ShowAlert = true;
   AlertClass = "alert-success";
   AlertMessage = "version updated";
   await Task.Delay(1);
  }
    catch (Exception)
  {
   ShowAlert = true;
    AlertClass = "alert-danger";
   AlertMessage = "error in update version";
   await Task.Delay(1);
  }
 }
}

@if (ShowAlert)
{
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="=col-sm-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <div class="alert @AlertClass mt-2 p-0" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="CloseAlert">
                  <span class="bi-x-circle"></span></button>
                @AlertMessage
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

@code
{
[Parameter] public bool ShowAlert { get; set; } = false;
[Parameter] public string AlertClass { get; set; } = "alert-info";
[Parameter] public string AlertMessage { get; set; }

private void CloseAlert()
{
    ShowAlert = false;
}
 }



The component doesn't render on subsequent button clicks because you're setting the property in the child.  As the parameter is a primitive type, there's no linkage between the child value and the parent field.  ShowAlert in the parent will always be true, so the Renderer detects no parameter changes and does nothing [doesn't call SetParametersAsync on the child, so no re-render of the child].  Put in a few console writes to check it's state.
You need to use binding to implement Show/Hide.  I've refactored your code to demonstrate how.
The Notification.  I've:

Fixed the onclicked to @onclicked.
Added an EventCallback to implement two way binding on ShowAlert.
Modified CloseAlert to call the EventCallback.
Changed the icon to a simple cross as I'm not sure what bi-x-circle is.

@if (this.ShowAlert)
{
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="=col-sm-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="alert @AlertClass mt-2 p-0" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" @onclick="CloseAlert">
                        <span>X</span>
                    </button>
                    @this.AlertMessage
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool ShowAlert { get; set; } = false;
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> ShowAlertChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string AlertClass { get; set; } = "alert-info";
    [Parameter] public string? AlertMessage { get; set; }

    private void CloseAlert()
    {
        this.ShowAlertChanged.InvokeAsync(false);
    }
}

And Home which I've refactored to demonstrate functionality.
Notification is now wired to use two way binding @bind-ShowAlert="ShowAlert".
The Notification close button click passes false back to the parent through the binding which sets ShowAlert in the parent.
Event Callbacks are UI events so trigger a render of the parent.  The renderer detects the change to ShowAlert and calls SetParametersAsync on Notification with the new false value.  It renders and hides it's content.
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<Notification @bind-ShowAlert="@ShowAlert" AlertClass="@AlertClass" AlertMessage="@AlertMessage" />

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="() => this.CheckProductVersion(true)">Check Version Success</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="() => this.CheckProductVersion(false)">Check Version Failure</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="this.CloseNotification">Close Notification</button>
</div>
@code
{
    private bool ShowAlert { get; set; }
    private string AlertClass { get; set; } = "alert-info";
    private string? AlertMessage { get; set; }

    private async Task CheckProductVersion(bool error)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);

        if (error)
        {
            //await UpdateWorker.CheckUpdate();
            ShowAlert = true;
            AlertClass = "alert-success";
            AlertMessage = "version updated";
        }
        else
        {
            ShowAlert = true;
            AlertClass = "alert-danger";
            AlertMessage = "error in update version";
        }
    }

    private void CloseNotification()
    {
        this.ShowAlert = false;
    }
}

